# How do I add sub collection automatically after adding a new document to a collection?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am adding a new document to a collection with angular@fire addDoc.  I want to add a sub-collection automatically after adding a new document to a collection.  basically I have to get the id of the new doc added

ts

```
  addTask(task: Task) { 
    collectionRef = collection(this.firestore, 'tasks');
    addDoc(collectionRef, { 
      ...task, 
      user: this.auth.currentUser?.uid 
    });
    
   // I want to get the id of the new document I have added to that collectionRef
    const id = "Get from new addDoc"; 
    const photoSubCollection = collection(this.firestore, `tasks/${id}/photos-sub-collection`);
    const docRef =  addDoc(photoSubCollection, []);
  }
```

All answers I searched for are at least 5 years old

Comment: You need to get the ID of the newly added document. So, chain ```.then()``` to ```addDoc()```. And the code may look like ```addDoc(collectionRef, {..}).then((docRef) => {..}```

Answer (score 0):

Using Keyboard Corporation comment, this is the solution that worked

```
addTask(task: Task) { 
  addDoc(this.collectionRef, { 
    ...task, 
    user: this.auth.currentUser?.uid 
  }).then((docRef) => {
    const id = docRef.id;
    const userSubCollection = collection(this.firestore, `tasks/${id}/photos-sub-collection`);
    addDoc(userSubCollection, {
      photo: "photos",
      photolist: []
    });
  });
}
```